# Insert key value pair at certain position in an object of javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object which consists of key-value pairs, I want to insert a key-value pair at a certain location, In the below example I want to insert it after the first key-value pair.

```
var obj = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};

console.log(obj);// {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}

obj.key3 = "value3";

console.log(obj);// {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3"}
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order, you cannot choose the order of keys

Comment: choose your data structure wisely.

Answer (score 13):

For add key value after certain index, We can use `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()`.

```
let obj = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};
let keyValues = Object.entries(obj); //convert object to keyValues ["key1", "value1"] ["key2", "value2"]
keyValues.splice(1,0, ["newKey","newValue"]); // insert key value at the index you want like 1.
let newObj = Object.fromEntries(keyValues) // convert key values to obj {key1: "value1", newKey: "newValue", key2: "value2"}
```

Answer (score 4):

### For ES5

There is no guarantee of order in Javascript objects. You just add new key value like `obj.key3 = "value3";` and `key3` will be available on `obj`.

### For ES6

```
function insertKey(key,value,obj,pos){
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((ac,a,i) => {
    if(i === pos) ac[key] = value;
    ac[a] = obj[a]; 
    return ac;
  },{})
}


data = insertKey('key3','value3',data,1);
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

In ES6+ environments, in which non-numeric properties are iterated over in insertion order, `delete` the `key2` first, then add it back in after setting `key3`:

```js
var obj = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};
const { key2 } = obj;
delete obj.key2;
obj.key3 = "value3";
obj.key2 = key2;
console.log(obj);
```

Still, this is a pretty odd thing to try to do, and isn't guaranteed to work in ES5. You might consider using an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for this purpose and use `reduce()` on `Object.keys`

```js
var data = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};

function insertKey(key,value,obj,pos){
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((ac,a,i) => {
    if(i === pos) ac[key] = value;
    ac[a] = obj[a]; 
    return ac;
  },{})
}


data = insertKey('key3','value3',data,1);
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Object properties in JavaScript have no defined order. There is no guarantee that the order in which you define them in your object literal will mean anything anywhere else.

[Some good info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: This is not true as of ES6 and beyond, which most modern browsers run on.

Comment: @CertainPerformance true, with some caveats, but I would argue that depending on the order of properties is a bad idea and that someone finding themself in such a situation should take a step back and have a hard look at why they need to do this

Comment: Quite often the reason for wanting a specific order is for generating a human-readable format such as XML, where it can be helpful to have keys in a particular order to make editing easier from the human side.

Comment: @Clonkex of course there's a use case for ordering elements in a collection. And for that, a different data structure should be used

Comment: @Kai Perhaps, but I've never seen a XML or JSON generator that _used_ a different data structure. For that reason and others it's completely reasonable to want to control the order of properties on an object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a descriptive implementation of a function which adds a key to an object at a specific index.

````
/**
 * adds a key-value pair to an object, ensuring that the key is added to the object at a certain order, specified by index
 *
 * for example:
 * ```ts
 * const object = { x: true, y: true, z: true }
 * const newObject = addKeyToObjectAtKeyIndex({ object, index: 1, key: 'a', value: true });
 * // newObject = { x: true, a: true, y: true, z: true }
 * ```
 */
const addKeyToObjectAtKeyIndex = ({
  object,
  index: requestedNewKeyIndex,
  key,
  value,
}: {
  object: Record<string, any>;
  index: number;
  key: string;
  value: any;
}) => {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce((newObject, thisKey, thisKeyIndex) => {
    if (thisKeyIndex === requestedNewKeyIndex) newObject[key] = value; // add the new key if its the index that was requested
    newObject[thisKey] = object[thisKey]; // now add the key that used to be at this index
    return newObject; // and continue
  }, {} as Record<string, any>);
};
````

Note: as of ES6, order in which keys were added to an object can matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/3068233